# Why isn't my IAuthorizationPolicy setting the Thread.CurrentPrincipal with my CustomPrincipal?

Tags: c#, wcf, wcf-security

For my WCF services I've implemented an IAuthorizationPolicy and hooked it up (and can confirm that it's being used).

In the Evaluate() method I am setting a custom principal like so:

```
evaluationContext.Properties["Principal"] = myCustomPrincipal;
```

However, when the service is invoked, Thread.CurrentPrincipal is a GenericPrincipal!

My service behavior is configured as follows:

```
<serviceAuthorization principalPermissionMode="Custom">
    <authorizationPolicies>
        <add policyType="MyNamespace.MyPrincipalAuthorizationPolicy, MyProject, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null" />
    </authorizationPolicies>
</serviceAuthorization>
```

I tried to use reflector to see what was going on but didn't see anything useful.

Am I doing it wrong? Is there some configuration I'm missing?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm not surprised there were tumbleweeds rolling around this question. There is nothing wrong with the approach I detailed in the question.

It turns out the problem was that I was using a custom `IInstanceProvider` (I didn't even think to include that information). If I stop using the custom instance provider everything works fine. But that's no good as I still want to use it.

So I found the only solution was to manually set the thread's current principal inside the instance provider.

The trick was getting hold of the principal I had set in the `IAuthorizationPolicy` - I managed to find it in the end using a rather cumbersome call via the static `OperationContext.Current`.

```
public object GetInstance(InstanceContext instanceContext, Message message)
{
    var principal =
        OperationContext.Current.ServiceSecurityContext.AuthorizationContext.Properties["Principal"] 
            as MyPrincipal;
    if (principal != null)
        Thread.CurrentPrincipal = principal;
    return ObjectFactory.GetInstance(_serviceType);
}
```

Of course, I'd be interested to know if there is a more elegant solution.

Comment: http://leastprivilege.com/2007/08/08/custom-principals-and-wcf/
Same solution here too

Comment: Saved my ass! after to much time spent not finding my principal